# Does pytorch DDP support torch.nn.ModuleList?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, distributed-computing

I want to parallel the torch.nn.ModuleList, for example

```
nets = torch.nn.ModuleList([net1, net2])
nets = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(nets)
```

But when I do the forward step with net1

```
x = nets[0](img)
```

I get an error: 'DistributedDataParallel' object is not subscriptable.

I tried

```
x = nets.module[0](img)
```

It works, but I'm not sure whether the DDP is working or it just runs on the first GPU?

If it just runs on the first GPU, how to parallel the forward step with net1

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it's not very clear what you were intending to parallelize.

`nets.modules[0]` is capturing a reference to your original network `net1` from an internal list, and so bypasses DDP (as well as bypassing `net2`).

(Distributed)DataParallel splits input across devices by splitting the input data. The (entire) model replicated once per device. A ModuleList is a list of Modules, and isn't something you'd typically pass to DDP.

Some possibilities:

- If your intent was to train two entirely different models on the same data, that's probably better done separately, e.g. possibly with two training loops. You don't need to chunk up the input data to do this.
- If the modules in your list are meant to be stitched together as layers in a larger model, e.g., `net1(net2(input))`, then you're probably looking for `nn.Sequential` not `nn.ModuleList`. The application of the distributed model would then be `nets(img)`. The module passed to DDP should itself have a callable forward method.
- If you intended to parallelize across modules/layers within a single model, you're probably actually looking for "model parallel" not "data parallel." There are tutorials for model parallelism which use `.to(device)` to move inputs across devices between layers, or which use PyTorch's RPC mechanisms if running on multiple hosts.